# How to implement the "exit" action in PyQt4?

Tags: python, pyqt4, exit

Many software have an "exit" action in the menubar items. I wonder know how to implement it in pyqt4.

I think only invoking the method `QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()` is not enough, because the application main window doesn’t disappear immediately when this method is called.

I think in order to "exit", we shouldn’t only call the `quit()` method but also should close the application main window at the same time.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the application will quit when the last window is closed - unless [quitOnLastWindowClosed](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.8-snapshot/qapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop) has been set to `False`.

So it is normally enough to just call `close()` on the main window.

One other thing to think about here, though, is whether any final actions should be taken before the application closes down (e.g. saving settings, asking the user whether they want to save any modified documents, etc).

So it is also common to reimplement the main window's [closeEvent](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.8-snapshot/qwidget.html#closeEvent) function.

Comment: so you mean QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit() is rarely used when quit the application .right ?

Comment: @user1485853. I'm not sure whether it's "rare" to use `quit`. But I would guess that using `close` is more common. Why does this matter to you? Is there a specific problem you are trying to solve?